# Как повернуть изображение в php и автоматически скропить чтобы не было полос по краям

Tags: php, gd

Использую GD библиотеку в php для поворота изображения.

```html
$src = imagerotate($source, $rotate, 0);
```

Но при повороте остаются черные "полосы" по краям, как автоматически сделать crop чтобы не было их. По аналогии кадрирования в фотошопе.

[image: Белым обвел какой должен быть кроп]

Comment: если угол поворота вы знаете, добавьте базовую тригонометрию, посчитайте размер полос да обрежьте. Либо возьмите дельту размеров предыдущего и нового изображения, поделите пополам, да на эту величину обрежьте (ну или вырежьте с этим отступом). было допустим 200х100. повернули получилось 240х120. разница 40/20. вот из точки `(20,10)` скопируйте прямоугольник исходных 200х100

Comment: Вот я тоже думал начать высчитывать как вырезать, попробую через второй вариант.